# How can i crash app with some log in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I want to crash my app forcefully but also want that app first print crash log on debuging window and than terminate app.

It's for testing purpose to test app to fetch crash log.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple :

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr.remove(at: 1)
```

Comment: I personally think that it is a very bad idea to introduce a bug in the code to solve this.

Comment: you can use fatalError instead.